# Facebook graph api picture from file upload?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the facebook graph api we have a attribute (picture) for attaching a image with a post. The source of the image has to be some location on the server. I have a file upload control on the page, can the uploaded image(not yet submitted) be used instead of images on the server?

I need to give the user an option to upload a image from his/her computer and that image will be posted on facebook using graph api. But since i don't have a path to the image, how would I do this?

Comment: just a suggestion, how about saving the user's uploaded photo on your server temporarily and using that path/filename to use on the posting.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From facebook documentation 'how to':

> Publishing an Photo
>
> In order to publish a photo to a user’s album, you must have the
>   publish_stream permission. With that granted, you can upload a photo
>   by issuing an HTTP POST request with the photo content and an optional
>   description to one these to Graph API connections:
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos - The photo will be
>   published to an album created for your app. We automatically create an
>   album for your app if it does not already exist. All photos uploaded
>   this way will then be added to this same album.
>
> ...
>
> Uploading a photo to your app’s album. Creating a new album and
>   uploading a photo to the album you create.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Also, you may upload your photo with Graph method `/me/photos`